# Interesting pattern in Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-series, approximation-theory

I was playing around with Fourier coefficients and I observed something very interesting[image]

The above is for the function $3x^2+2x^3$ for $100$ terms($-\pi$ to $\pi$ periodic).

The alternate coefficients seem to form a nice decay pattern. Initially, I guessed that this decay was exponential, but to my surprise, it was a polynomial decay, as I observed it with a curve fit.

[image]

While the other set of $b_k$s and the two other $a_k$ sets form a very similar decay pattern, they do not exactly coincide to such a great extent.

So my question is why these coefficients form such a nice alternating sequence and if it is possible to find an approximate curve fit function.

I tried to do find a relation between $a_{k+2}$ and $a_{k}$:

$$a_{k+2}-a_{k}=-2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin((k+1)x)\sin(x)dx$$

but this doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1464647/305862

Answer (score 3):

A succinct explanation can be given with [Bernoulli_polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials).

I will use interval $[-1,1]$ instead of $[-\pi,\pi]$ for my explanations.

Indeed,

1. As you can see in the Wikipedia reference : the complex Fourier series of $B_n(x)$ is :

$$B_n(x) = -\frac{n!}{(2\pi i)^n}\sum_{\matrix{k=-\infty\\ k\ne 0}}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^n}e^{2\pi ikx}\tag{1}$$

or :

$$B_n(x)=2\, \Re\left(-\frac{n!}{(2\pi i)^n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k^n}\, e^{2\pi i k x}\right)$$

(Thanks to @Steven Clark who has corrected an error of mine)

**Remark :** Identity (1), strictly speaking, is valid for $x \in [0,1]$ ; or, instead, for all $x$ under the condition of replacement, in the LHS, of $B_n(x)$ by a periodised version.

Remark : the real coefficients of the Fourier series of the $B_p(x)$ are (with classical notations)

- only with $a_k$ coefficients when $p$ is even.
- only with $b_k$ coefficients when $p$ is odd.

2. Polynomials $B_p(x), \ p \le n$ constitute a basis of the $(n+1)$ dimensional vector space of polynomials with degree $\le n$.

Therefore, any polynomial $P(x)$ with $\text{degree}(P)=n$ can be written :

$$P(x)=d_nB_n(x)+d_{n-1}B_{n-1}(x)+\cdots+d_0\underbrace{B_0(x)}_1$$

with coefficient $d_n \ne 0$ due to the necessary presence of a monomial in $x^n$.

This $d_n$ coefficient will have a long-term decisive influence.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3981019/305862) for a recurrence proof of the first formula.

Comment: Since $B_0(x)=1$, $P(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_n\, B_n(x)$, and for the case in the question above $2 x^3+3 x^2=\frac{3}{2} B_0(x)+5 B_1(x)+6 B_2(x)+2 B_3(x)$. The Fourier series for $B_n(x)$ is over all integer $k\ne 0$, so the formula in your answer above is not quite correct. Also the Fourier series for $B_n(x)$ is only valid on the interval $0<x<1$, whereas the question is about a Fourier series on the interval $-\pi<x<\pi$.

Comment: Your explanation of the Fourier series is getting more confusing to me. You went from $B_n(x)$ to $B_k(x)$ and I believe $a_n$ and $b_n$ should actually be $a_k$ and $b_k$, (or did you mean something like $a_{n,k}$ and $b_{n,k}$?). I believe the Fourier series is actually $$B_n(x)=-\frac{n!}{(2\pi i)^n}\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}  \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}  0 & k=0 \\  \frac{1}{k^n} & k\ne 0 \\ \end{array}\right.\right)\, e^{2\pi i k x}=2\, \Re\left(-\frac{n!}{(2\pi i)^n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k^n}\, e^{2\pi i k x}\right),\ 0<x<1$$ where $\Re(...)$ is the real part.

Comment: Complex fourier series index starts at 1?

Comment: An interesting [document](https://backend.orbit.dtu.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/81742991/5.pdf) about Bernoulli polynomials and their Fourier series.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is intended to supplement [the original answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4766559) posted by Jean Marie.

---

The $2 \pi$-periodic Fourier series for $f(x)=2 x^3+3 x^2$ is

$$f(x)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=-K}^K \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}  \pi ^2 & k=0 \\  \frac{\left(2\, (-1)^k\, \left(k\, \left(3+i\, \pi^2\, k\right)-6\, i\right)\right)}{k^3} & k\ne 0 \\ \end{array}\right.\right)\, e^{i kx}\right),\ -\pi<x<\pi\tag{1}.$$

---

Consider the following $2 \pi$-periodic Fourier series for the Bernoulli polynomials $B_0(x)$ to $B_3(x)$

$$B_0(x)=1\tag{2}$$

$$B_1(x)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=-K}^K \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{1}{2} & k=0 \\
 \frac{i (-1)^k}{k} & k\ne 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right) e^{i k x}\right),\ -\pi<x<\pi\tag{3}$$

$$B_2(x)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=-K}^K \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{6} \left(1+2 \pi ^2\right) & k=0 \\
 \frac{(-1)^k (2-i k)}{k^2} & k\ne 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right) e^{i k x}\right),\ -\pi<x<\pi\tag{4}$$

$$B_3(x)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=-K}^K \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{\pi ^2}{2} & k=0 \\
 \frac{i (-1)^k \left(k \left(6 i+k+2 k \pi ^2\right)-12\right)}{2 k^3} & k\ne 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right) e^{i k x}\right),\ -\pi<x<\pi\tag{5}$$

---

Noting that

$$f(x)=2 x^3+3 x^2=\frac{3}{2} B_0(x)+5 B_1(x)+6 B_2(x)+2 B_3(x)\tag{6}$$

formulas (1) to (5) above lead to the equivalency

$$\left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \pi ^2 & k=0 \\
 \frac{2 (-1)^k \left(k \left(3+i \pi ^2 k\right)-6 i\right)}{k^3} & k\ne 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right)=\frac{3}{2} \delta(k)+5 \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{1}{2} & k=0 \\
 \frac{i (-1)^k}{k} & k\ne 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right)+6 \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{6} \left(1+2 \pi ^2\right) & k=0 \\
 \frac{(-1)^k (2-i k)}{k^2} & k\ne 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right)+2 \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{\pi ^2}{2} & k=0 \\
 \frac{i (-1)^k \left(k \left(6 i+k+2 k \pi ^2\right)-12\right)}{2 k^3} & k\ne 0 \\\end{array}\right.\right)\tag{7}$$

where $\delta(k)$ is the [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

---

Likewise, the 1-periodic Fourier series for $f(x)=2 x^3+3 x^2$ and $B_n(x)$ illustrated in formulas (8) and (9) below and the relationship illustrated in formula (6) above lead to the equivalency illustrated in formula (10) below.

$$f(x)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=-K}^K \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{3}{2} & k=0 \\
 \frac{\pi k (6+5 i \pi  k)-3 i}{2 \pi ^3 k^3} & k\ne 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right) e^{i 2 \pi k x}\right),\ 0<x<1\tag{8}$$

$$B_n(x)=\left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & n=0 \\
 \underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=-K}^K \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & k=0 \\
 -\frac{n!}{(2 \pi  i k)^n} & k\ne 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right) e^{2 \pi i k x}\right) & n>0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right),\ 0<x<1\tag{9}$$

$$\left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{3}{2} & k=0 \\
 \frac{\pi  k (6+5 i \pi  k)-3 i}{2 \pi ^3 k^3} & k\ne 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right)
=\frac{3}{2} \delta_k
+5 \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & k=0 \\
 -\frac{1!}{(2 \pi  i k)^1} & k\ne 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right)
+6 \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & k=0 \\
 -\frac{2!}{(2 \pi  i k)^2} & k\ne 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right)
+2 \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & k=0 \\
 -\frac{3!}{(2 \pi  i k)^3} & k\ne 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right)\tag{10}$$